# pthreads mutex: protect member of a struct

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

Given a mutex which protects a struct I would like to protect a member of the struct `mystruct` named 'tasklist`. Will the use of the mutex in the following scenario be enough?

Code:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&th_mutex);
addNewItem(&mystruct);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&th_mutex);
```

Conditions:

- The list `tasklist` is of fixed length n.
- If a new item is to be added to this list when it is already full, the array is extended by creating a list of size 2n, 3n,... and doing a memcpy with the old list.
- This is all done in `addNewItem`.

Reason I am asking is I am experiencing an issue where it seems that iterating over the items on tasklist seems to be pointing to a memory block which has already been freed. I am not certain whether this is the place of the old list but because the original issue takes a lot of attempts to reproduce I am doing a lot of code inspection at the moment.

Comment: It depends on how the code is written that uses the `tasklist`.  If the code caches the value of the pointer `tasklist` and it changes while the code is using the cached value, you'll be accessing the old pointer.  If the only access to `tasklist` is via `mystruct.tasklist`, you might be OK.  We'd probably need to an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing).

Comment: Are you also locking the mutex when iterating over the items?

Comment: You can make the problem easier to reproduce by reallocating the list every time `addNewItem` is called, even when the size doesn't change. And before you `free` the old memory, fill it with something that's guaranteed to cause a segfault, so you can catch it in the debugger.

Comment: Note: If you think you need to lock a mutex in _one_ place where your code accesses some data structure, then you need to lock it in _every_ place where your code accesses the data.

Comment: It would probably be worth embedding the mutex in the structure, so that each separate copy of the structure has its own separate mutex to lock access to the `tasklist` in the structure.  You might lock the mutex before any access to the structure members, or you might use it solely to protect the `tasklist` — that's a judgement call you'll need to make.